# Generating chess knight's moves for a given depth

Tags: java, recursion, chess

I am writing a function that get's the initial position of the knight on the board as an argument and a number of moves the knight will do and returns a list of all the fields the knight will be able to achieve for the given number of moves. I ran a JUnit test and for the depth 1, 2 and 3 the function works correctly, however for the depth 4, the list misses 4 fields. I've got no idea, where the mistake could be. Here's the code:

```
Knight.java

private boolean moveIsPossible (Position pos) {     
    return (pos.x >= 0 && pos.x <= 7) && (pos.y >= 0 && pos.y <= 7);        
}

int [] x = {1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1};
int [] y = {2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2};

private ArrayList<Position> reachableSet = new ArrayList<Position>(); 
@Override
public ArrayList<Position> getReachableSet(Position pos, int numberofMoves) {
    if (!reachableSet.contains(pos)) reachableSet.add(pos);
    if (numberofMoves == 0) return reachableSet;
    ArrayList<Position> moves = new ArrayList<Position>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {           
        Position candidate = new Position (pos.x+x[i], pos.y+y[i]);
        if (!moveIsPossible(candidate)) continue;
        if (!reachableSet.contains(candidate)) {
            moves.add(candidate);
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < moves.size(); j++) {
        reachableSet = getReachableSet(moves.get(j), numberofMoves-1);
    }
    return reachableSet;
}
```

Here's the Position class:

```
public class Position implements Comparable<Position> {
/**
 * The row on the chess board
 */
public int x;

/**
 * The column on the chess board
 */
public int y;

/**
 * Create a new position object
 * @param x the row on the chess board
 * @param y the column on the chess board
 */
public Position(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
}
```

**Here's the JUnit test I use.**

```
public class Tests {
private IKnight knight;

@Before
public void setup() {
    knight = KnightFactory.create();
}

private String printSet(ArrayList<Position> positions)
{
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("\n  ");
    for (int x=0; x<IKnight.boardSize; x++) {
        s.append(x);
    }
    s.append("\n  ");
    for (int x=0; x<IKnight.boardSize; x++) {
        s.append("-");
    }
    s.append("\n");

    for (int y=0; y<IKnight.boardSize; y++) {
        s.append(y).append("|");
        for (int x=0; x<IKnight.boardSize; x++) {
            if (positions.contains(new Position(x, y))) {
                s.append("X");
            } else {
                s.append(" ");
            }
        }
        s.append("\n");
    }
    return s.toString();
}

private void compare(ArrayList<Position> result, int[]... expected) {
    Collections.sort(result);

    ArrayList<Position> expectedVec = new ArrayList<Position>(expected.length);
    for (int[] pos : expected) {
        expectedVec.add(new Position(pos[0], pos[1]));
    }
    Collections.sort(expectedVec);

    Assert.assertEquals(printSet(result), expectedVec.toString(), result.toString());
}

@Test
public void noHop() {
    ArrayList<Position> result = knight.getReachableSet(new Position(4, 4), 0);
    int expected[][] = { { 4, 4 } };
    compare(result, expected);
}

@Test
public void oneHop() {
    ArrayList<Position> result = knight.getReachableSet(new Position(4, 4), 1);
    int expected[][] = { { 4, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 6, 5 }, { 6, 3 }, { 5, 2 },
            { 3, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 2, 5 }, { 3, 6 } };
    compare(result, expected);
}

@Test
public void oneHopCorner() {
    ArrayList<Position> result = knight.getReachableSet(new Position(0, 0), 1);
    int expected[][] = { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 1 } };
    compare(result, expected);
}

@Test
public void twoHopsCorner() {
    ArrayList<Position> result = knight.getReachableSet(new Position(0, 0), 2);
    int expected[][] = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 2 }, { 0, 4 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 3 },
            { 2, 0 }, { 2, 1 }, { 2, 4 }, { 3, 1 }, { 3, 3 }, { 4, 0 },
            { 4, 2 } };
    compare(result, expected);
}

@Test
public void threeHops() {
    ArrayList<Position> result = knight.getReachableSet(new Position(4, 4), 3);
    int expected[][] = {{ 0, 1 }, { 0, 2 }, { 0, 3 }, { 0, 4 },
            { 0, 5 }, { 0, 6 }, { 0, 7 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 2 },
            { 1, 3 }, { 1, 4 }, { 1, 5 }, { 1, 6 }, { 1, 7 }, { 2, 0 },
            { 2, 1 }, { 2, 3 }, { 2, 4 }, { 2, 5 }, 
            { 2, 7 }, { 3, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 3, 3 }, { 3, 4 },
            { 3, 5 }, { 3, 6 }, { 3, 7 }, { 4, 0 }, { 4, 1 }, { 4, 2 },
            { 4, 3 }, { 4, 4 }, { 4, 5 }, { 4, 6 }, { 4, 7 }, { 5, 0 },
            { 5, 1 }, { 5, 2 }, { 5, 3 }, { 5, 4 }, { 5, 5 }, { 5, 6 },
            { 5, 7 }, { 6, 0 }, { 6, 1 }, { 6, 3 }, { 6, 4 },
            { 6, 5 }, { 6, 7 }, { 7, 0 }, { 7, 1 }, { 7, 2 },
            { 7, 3 }, { 7, 4 }, { 7, 5 }, { 7, 6 }, { 7, 7 }, };
    compare(result, expected);
}

@Test
public void fourHops() {
    ArrayList<Position> result = knight.getReachableSet(new Position(4, 4), 4);
    int expected[][] = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 2 }, { 0, 3 }, { 0, 4 },
            { 0, 5 }, { 0, 6 }, { 0, 7 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 2 },
            { 1, 3 }, { 1, 4 }, { 1, 5 }, { 1, 6 }, { 1, 7 }, { 2, 0 },
            { 2, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 2, 4 }, { 2, 5 }, { 2, 6 },
            { 2, 7 }, { 3, 0 }, { 3, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 3, 3 }, { 3, 4 },
            { 3, 5 }, { 3, 6 }, { 3, 7 }, { 4, 0 }, { 4, 1 }, { 4, 2 },
            { 4, 3 }, { 4, 4 }, { 4, 5 }, { 4, 6 }, { 4, 7 }, { 5, 0 },
            { 5, 1 }, { 5, 2 }, { 5, 3 }, { 5, 4 }, { 5, 5 }, { 5, 6 },
            { 5, 7 }, { 6, 0 }, { 6, 1 }, { 6, 2 }, { 6, 3 }, { 6, 4 },
            { 6, 5 }, { 6, 6 }, { 6, 7 }, { 7, 0 }, { 7, 1 }, { 7, 2 },
            { 7, 3 }, { 7, 4 }, { 7, 5 }, { 7, 6 }, { 7, 7 }, };
    compare(result, expected);
}
```

Comment: What is the code of Position and moveIsPossible ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I mistyped the word, there's only one Knight, sorry for confusing

Comment: "I ran a JUnit test and for the depth 1, 2 and 3 the function works correctly, however for the depth 4, the list misses 4 fields" - What's your starting position in that test? Are those four moves possible given that starting position? Since you don't show us the test, or the definition of `moveIsPossible()`, there's no way for us to answer those questions.

Comment: And as a general comment: add an `equals()` and `hashCode()` to your `Position` object, and use an actual `Set` for `reachableSet`. As it is, your code is broken, because `contains()` will always return `false`.

Comment: @kdgregory the definition of `moveIsPossible` is included in the description. Could you explain why `contains` will always return `false` as you mentioned?

Comment: @kdgregory I added the JUnit code to the description

Comment: Sorry, missed that. But you still need to show your test. I'm betting that the starting position is near a corner, and therefore the moves are (correctly) not possible. As for `contains()`, you need to understand [the difference between instance and object equality](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html). Without defining an `equals()` method specific to your class, you get instance equality. And two `new` instances will always be different.

Comment: One other code-review comment: consider the lifetime of `reachableSet`. If it's to be regenerated within this method, create it within the method. Otherwise, recognize that it may already have data present (although not in a unit test, which should create a new instance each time).

Comment: @kdgregory I didn't know that, thanks. Will try use the native `equals()` method.